# Setting tab order in wpf when use from UserControls?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, tab-ordering

I have a User Control like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySample.customtextbox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="Ytextbox"  Background="Yellow"/>
</Grid>
```

And I use this control in a window and set tab orders...but when my window is loaded, the tab order is not working correctly!!!
my window code:

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MySample"  x:Class="MySample.window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="window" Height="300" Width="600">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <my:customtextbox Grid.Column="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" InfoText="{Binding msg}" Height="20"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding msg}" Height="20" Background="Gold"></TextBox>
    <my:customtextbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" InfoText="{Binding msg}" Height="20"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding msg}" Height="20" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3" Background="Gold"></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, WPF reads all the controls, inside and outside your UserControl, at the same tab level. Since the controls inside your UserControl do not have a TabIndex specified, they get tabbed to last after the first tab cycle.

The workaround I usually use is to set the `IsTabStop="False"` on my `UserControl` (to prevent tabbing onto the UserControl itself), and then inside the `UserControl` use a `TemplateBinding` to bind to the inner Controls `TabIndex` to the UserControl's `TabIndex`

```
<TextBox x:Name="Ytextbox"  Background="Yellow"
         TabIndex="{Binding Path=TabIndex, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:customtextbox}}}"/>
```

and

```
<my:customtextbox IsTabStop="False" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" 
                  Grid.Column="1" InfoText="{Binding msg}" Height="20"/>
```

Comment: Or you can use `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"` on `<my:usercontrol>` when your custom usercontrol has more controls which have their own specific tab order valid only with usercontrol

Comment: @psulek: I suggest You make this an answer, it helped in my situation, maybe somebody else will find it useful (couple of user controls in user control, coupled with some regular widgets).

Comment: @psulek, I have been searching for a solution all over the internet for weeks.... And the answer was sitting on a comment.  Man you saved me... Thanks Alot....